# help with c# array

Tags: c#

I have a  datatable with two columns. I want to store the rows of each column in an array so that I can return rows for each individual column. This way I believe I can populate a list box(the option text as one column and the option value as the other column).

Here is what I started out with:

```
public object dbAccess2()
{
    ArrayList arg = new ArrayList();
    DataTable myTable = GenericDataAccess.ExecuteSelectCmd("Vehicle_GetMakes");


        foreach (DataRow dRow in myTable.Rows)
        {
            arg.Add(dRow["VehicleMake"]);
            arg.Add(dRow["VehicleMakeId"]);
        }

    return arg.ToArray();   
}
```

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: Do you want to load the data from the DataTable in a listbox? (if you want to keep the separate columns as they are in the DataTable you might want to consider a ListView or DataGridView)

Comment: Surely you can just use the DataTable as the datasource on your list box, setting the DataTextField and DataValueField to your column names?

Comment: As a side note; don't use `ArrayList`. Use `List<T>` instead (in your code sample that would be `List<DataRow>`, even though it might be better to design a specific type, as suggested in the answer by @Yogesh).

Comment: I should have been more clear, I will be using jQuery ajax to get 1 column of values for a listbox and the other column as each options value. I don't want each options value based off of the index of the array, as I use the value in my database stored procedures to assign things to categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a class to hold each individual row in this case and use a `List<T>` to hold the data, like this:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string Make { get, set };
    public string MakeId { get, set };
}

..

List<Vehicle> Vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();

..

foreach (DataRow dRow in myTable.Rows)
{
    Vehicles.Add(
        new Vehicle {
            Make = arg.Add(dRow["VehicleMake"]),
            MakeId = arg.Add(dRow["VehicleMakeId"])
        });
}
```

And later, you can easily populate a listbox with this list:

```
listBox.DataSource = Vehicles;
listBox.DisplayMember = "Make";
```

But I think you may want to use a ListView probably.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh, my plan is populate an html listbox using jQuery ajax. I am able to do that with my old code, but the index of the array got stored as the option value, which I need the index to be my id field of my db column.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `ArrayList` class, it's practically obsolete. Use arrays or generic lists instead, so that you get a typed result.

You can get the columns into lists like this:

```
List<string> makes = myTable.Rows.Select(r => (string)r["VehicleMake"]).ToList();
List<int> makeIds = myTable.Rows.Select(r => (int)r["VehicleMakeId"]).ToList();
```

Or into arrays:

```
string[] makes = myTable.Rows.Select(r => (string)r["VehicleMake"]).ToArray();
int[] makeIds = myTable.Rows.Select(r => (int)r["VehicleMakeId"]).ToArray();
```

An alternative to populating a dropdown (as that is what I assume that you mean, as a ListBox doesn't have options) from arrays is to use data binding:

```
theDropdown.DataTextField = "VehicleMake";
theDropdown.DataValueField = "VehicleMakeId";
theDropdown.DataSource = myTable;
theDropdown.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification that ArrayList is obsolete, I was wondering why there was an ArrayList and a List<>.

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting is to manipulate real objects without the benefit of object design, invoking raw data instead. This has very broad and far-reaching problems and is quite far behind current development strategies - to broad to go into here but not least of your problems is building in a brittle coupling between your application and your database.

Step one is to model an actual Vehicle class.

```
public class Vehicle  
{  
    public string MakeId { get; set; }

    public string Make { get; set; }          
}
```

Step two is to build a managing class for your Vehicles ("Fleet" perhaps?) which can abstract the Vehicle collection behind an IEnumerable interface. Internally you will store the Vehicles collection as a concrete generic collection (a List or Dictionary most likely) and avoid at all costs the really-should-be-considered-obsolete ArrayList structure.

```
public class Fleet
{
    private List<Vehicle> _vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();

    public IEnumerable<Vehicle> Vehicles { return this._vehicles;}
}
```

Step three is to internalise to this class (or a class behind this one or behind *that* one etc, etc) the CRUD operations which will interact with the Database stored data. That's truly an implementation detail, but one you'll apply for all similar classes throughout your architecture.

At this point you'll be able to work with the IEnumerable property directly with standard Databinding methods.